# How to assign large multi-line text into string in C#?

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to initialize a string variable with a large text with 50+ lines. But the string variable isn't taking the anything after the second line. I tried using StringBuilder, which failed as well.

```
string longText = "";
```

sample text:

> foo bar foo bar bar
>   bar bar bar foo foo tiger
>
> lime orange lemon bar bar
>   ...etc ..

There's not quotes in the text, simply has new lines. I could regex and replace the newlines with some special character, but that feels like over engineering it. Any simple method I'm missing out??

Comment: What does "*which failed as well*" mean? Sample of the result would help as well as the exact code snippet you have implemented.

Comment: Use `@`: `string longText = @"this is long text with new lines that I can't show in a comment";`

Comment: @ sign works. Thanks. I'll accept one of the answers below. Feel like super silly question, but happy to get this working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**the @ string literal**](http://dotnetslackers.com/CSharp/re-51752%5FThe%5FChash%5FString%5FLiteral.aspx) before the string assignment:

```
string a = @"
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate 
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id 
est laborum.";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string longText = @"
sample text:
foo bar foo bar bar
bar bar bar foo foo tiger

lime orange lemon bar bar
etc
etc .. ";
```

Comment: Once again, a bad answer - you did "fix" this one but failed to mention **what exactly** the solution was - you should give an explanation of what the `@` character does when used with a string literal. Don't just submit a code block and no other explanation.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!